# What does "be never happy" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I have found these on the Web:

1. No matter what I do, *she's never happy.* Ever since I was little, and for as long as I can remember, she's never satisfied with anything I do.
2. "*She's never happy* when I'm around," she says. "I don't think she likes me very much."
3. I've tried to please her in every way I can, but *she's never happy.*
4. *He's never happy,* he's never satisfied, he's just a...
5. *He's never happy* with anything I make for supper, so I should tell you that you probably don't have anything that will work for me.
6. *He's never happy* with what he's doing.

What does "She's/He's never happy" mean? Is it okay to interpret it as "She/He didn't show me a happy look, don't, and highly probably won't"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This phrase is quite literal.  It means that the person never has the state of being happy under the conditions described.  For instance, in your first example, it would me that the person is never pleased with what you do, regardless of what it is.

The implication is that the person will be displeased regardless of your actions.